# Angular 6 return Observable<Car> after a subscribe of RxJs zip

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I want return a `Observable<Car>`

```
import { zip, Observable } from 'rxjs';

public createMedia(car: Car, dataUrl: string): Observable<Car> {
    const url = this.carDataService.createCar(car);
    const blob = this.dataUrlToBlob(dataUrl);
    const z = zip(url, blob);
    z.subscribe(val => this.saveData(val));
    return ...???(I want return Observable<Car> from saveData(val))
}

saveData(val): Observable<Car> {
  console.log('saveData => val 0: ' + val[0].id + ' val 1: ' + val[1]);
  return this.mediaDataService.saveBytes(val[0].id, val[1]);
}

const oMedia: Observable<Car> = this.createMedia(media);
oMedia.pipe(
  tap(media => console.log('Media created with id: ' + media.id)),
  map(media => this.setMediaId(step, media))
);
```

Comment: return saveData(val) ?

Comment: @JFPicard, where you past this ?

Comment: How do you get a Car from `val`?

Comment: Hi @sgrillon,
in order to help you, I need more details
1. creat car return URL?
2. the const url is Observable?
3. the blob is Observable?
4. where u get the car instance you want to return as Observable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe to the `zip` result and use `flatMap` operator:

```
import { flatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { zip, Observable } from 'rxjs';

public createMedia(car: Car, dataUrl: string): Observable<Car> {
  const url = this.carDataService.createCar(car);
  const blob = this.dataUrlToBlob(dataUrl);

  return zip(url, blob).pipe(
    flatMap(val => this.saveData(val))
  );
}
```

And don't forget to subscribe to the `createMedia` result instead.

```
oMedia.subscribe(car => console.log('Media created with id: ' + car.id));
```

Comment: saveData never call

Comment: do you subscribe to the result of `createMedia(...)`?

Comment: yes, i edit your answer with import and caller, Thank you for your reply